# Skip Validation Page after Google/Facebook Sign-Up Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I want to disable/skip the validation page which ask to modify Display Name/First Name/Last Name after a Google/Facebook Sign-up. I want to be directly redirected to my app. I'm using AD B2C custom policies.

I have tried to delete InputClaims and OutputClaims in `<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Social">` but it not works (
Error with claim sub not being in the claims collection)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must remove orchestration step #4 from the user journey so that the new user isn't prompted for any input claims:

> **Note:** After you have removed orchestration step #4, you must re-number the orchestration steps that followed it.

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>objectId</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Social" />
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Instead, orchestration step #5 will create the **user** object, with claims that are received from the external identity provider:

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>objectId</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: Chris, it works thank you. I want to send you some turkish delight.

Comment: Excellent!, @Memo, I love turkish delight. :)

Comment: Hey Chris... could you shed some light here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58276894/114029 I guess I'll have to play with `SelfAsserted-Social` technical profile... but I'm not sure if it's valid for what I want to achieve.