# Remove input form from social signup (with account linkage) to make sign up process seamless for the new user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I implemented & integrated the code/logic from the following as part of my signup process for a project I'm currently on to link social media account & local account in AAD: [AccountLinkExtensions.xml](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/b2acbcfef213413be8747caae98482883a556bca/policies/auto-account-linking/policy/AccountLinkExtensions.xml). 
Everything works perfectly regarding account linking, however, I'm struggling with making the sign up process seamless for a user who signs in for the first time using social for e.g. Google. 
I do not want that a user is required to input/edit their Display Name, Given Name & Last Name & to have to click 'Continue'. I would like the signing up process to be seamless, just like it is if they had previously signed up for a local account.

I was able to achieve this seamlessness using the following suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54239597/skip-validation-page-after-google-facebook-sign-up-azure-ad-b2c) but that was prior to me upgrading my custom policies to handle account linking. 
Now my code uses the technical profile [SelfAsserted-Social-v2](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/b2acbcfef213413be8747caae98482883a556bca/policies/auto-account-linking/policy/AccountLinkExtensions.xml#L595) & I don't seem to be able to simply omit this as part of the orchestration/signup process as it seems like it is also responsible to generate a random password for a local account created in the process. 
I'm still fairly new to Azure AD B2C custom policy development & I'm really stuck on this. 
The objective is to simply use the Display Name, Given Name & Last Name already provided by Identity Provider e.g. Google & to make the sign up/in process seamless, I would very much appreciate any help I can get to be able to achieve that. 
[Unwanted input form (Screenshot1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot27G.png)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this is to ensure these fields are populated if they are not passed by the social provider.

If they are passed, just create a TP with "CreateRandomPassword" and "AAD-UserWriteUsingUserIdentity".